How to Select Rows by Custom Index after Filtering in Polars, Similar to .loc in Pandas?
In Pandas, after filtering/sorting a DataFrame, the row indices might become non-sequential (e.g., [0, 10, 4]). If I use .loc[10], I can retrieve the row corresponding to the original index 10 from the DataFrame, which is now the second row in the filtered/sorted DataFrame:
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})
filtered_df = df.loc[[0, 10, 4]]

# Retrieves the row where the original index is 4
print(filtered_df.loc[4])

This would output:
A    4
Name: 4, dtype: int64

I am trying to replicate this behavior in Polars. To preserve the original row indices after filtering, I created an index column using .with_row_index(). However, I am unsure how to proceed from here. I need an efficient solution that allows me to use a similar .loc functionality to select multiple rows by their original indices in Polars after filtering or sorting.

You can simply filter using the index column as follows.
Setup.
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "x": [11, None, 3, None, 5]
})

df_filtered = (
    df
    .with_row_index()
    .filter(
        pl.col("x").is_not_null()
    )
)

shape: (3, 2)
┌───────┬─────┐
│ index ┆ x   │
│ ---   ┆ --- │
│ u32   ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═════╡
│ 0     ┆ 11  │
│ 2     ┆ 3   │
│ 4     ┆ 5   │
└───────┴─────┘

Filter based on index column.
df_filtered.filter(pl.col("index") == 4)

shape: (1, 2)
┌───────┬─────┐
│ index ┆ x   │
│ ---   ┆ --- │
│ u32   ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═════╡
│ 4     ┆ 5   │
└───────┴─────┘

Note that the filtering on the index column can vary (i.e. if you have a list of indices pl.Expr.is_in can be used; if you have a dataframe of indices an inner-join can be used, etc).

This approach works well for small DataFrames and when trying to .loc on a sigle row, but what if my DataFrame has 100k samples and I need to perform .loc on 10k rows? I’m looking for an efficient solution that can handle datasets with a large number of rows

@Míriam In this case, using either pl.Expr.is_in or an inner-join would be applicable.

@Míriam What is the format of the 10k index rows (python list, polars series, polars dataframe, etc)?

I have both a polars series and a polars dataframe

@Míriam I'd go with an inner-join then df_filtered.join(df_indices, on="index").
